# How to read numbers from extracted lines (deleting repeated numbers)

Tags: regex, perl, xml-parsing, extract

I need to convert parts of a .txt file in this format (first by matching "SchDay")

```
<SchDay>
  <Name>School Occup WD</Name>
  <Type>Fraction</Type>
  <Hr index="0">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="1">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="2">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="3">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="4">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="5">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="6">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="7">0.05</Hr>
  <Hr index="8">0.75</Hr>
  ....
```

to look like this (values come first, and “steps” need just the 2 ends defined):

```
0.00, 0.00,

0.00, 6.00,    <- end of step

0.05, 7.00,

0.75, 8.00,

...
```

Etc

This is what I have so far:

```
open (OUTFILE, ">C:/begperl/parts/all1.txt")|| die "Can't open it";

my @files = glob ("*.txt");

for (@files) {

    open (INFILE, $_) || die "can't open infile";
    @lines = <INFILE>;
    my %answer;
    $regex = '<SchDay';
    for my $idx (0..$#lines) {
    if ($lines[$idx] =~ /$regex/) {
        for $ii (($idx + 3)..($idx + 26)){
        {$answer{$ii} = ($lines[$ii]);}
        }
    }
    foreach $key (sort keys %answer) { print OUTFILE "$answer{$key}\n" }
    }
close (INFILE);}
```

So I have the lines I want. Now I need to extract just the numbers, including decimal points, and then delete consecutive hours with the same values.

Comment: Go for it ! If you have a specific question let us know

Answer (score 1):

You document has an XML structure. You are much better off exploiting that by using a proper XML parser. [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3a%3aTwig) allows you to easily isolate the parts of an XML document in which you are interested. In this case, all we want are `<Hr>` elements that occur within `<SchDay>` elements:

```
my $parser = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots => { 'SchDay/Hr' => \&do_print },
);
```

This just tells the parser to invoke the `do_print` sub for each `<Hr>` within a `<SchDay>`. `do_print` will be called with two arguments: The parser instance we just created and the element. Use `$element->att('index')` to access the value of the index attribute, and `$attr->text` to get the text of the attribute, and format and print them. Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $parser = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots => { 'SchDay/Hr' => \&do_print },
);

$parser->parse(\*DATA);

sub do_print {
    my $parser = shift;
    my $element = shift;

    printf "%.02f,%.02f,\n",
        $element->text,
        $element->att('index'),
    ;
    $parser->purge;
    return;
}

__DATA__
<SchDay>
  <Name>School Occup WD</Name>
  <Type>Fraction</Type>
  <Hr index="0">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="1">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="2">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="3">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="4">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="5">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="6">0</Hr>
  <Hr index="7">0.05</Hr>
  <Hr index="8">0.75</Hr>
</SchDay>
```

Output:

```
0.00, 0.00,
0.00, 1.00,
0.00, 2.00,
0.00, 3.00,
0.00, 4.00,
0.00, 5.00,
0.00, 6.00,
0.05, 7.00,
0.75, 8.00,
```

As for what needs to be fixed with your code … Here are some points I hope will help you write better Perl:

```
open (OUTFILE, ">C:/begperl/parts/all1.txt")|| die "Can't open it";
```

- Don't use bareword filehandles such as `OUTFILE`. They are package variables which means they are subject to action at a distance. Instead, declare a lexical variable in the smallest applicable scope as in:

  ```
   my $filename = 'C:/begperl/parts/all1.txt';

   open my $outfile, '>', $filename
        or die "Failed to open '$filename': $!";
  ```
- Do name the loop variable in `for` loops:

  ```
   for my $input_file (@files) {
        open my $input, '<', $input_file
            or die "Failed to open '$input_file': $!";
  ```
- Don't slurp when line-by-line processing will do. That is, don't use `@lines = <INFILE>;` to read all of the lines of the file in one go.
- Don't use magical constants such as the `3` and the `26` below. Instead, give them names. For example:

  ```
         use Const::Fast;
         const my $HR_BEGIN => 3;
         const my $HR_END   => 26;
  ```

But, that is still too fragile. What if the number of lines of `<Hr>` elements changes? After all, this is an XML document, and you could just as easily have the next batch with

```
<Hr index="5">
   0.00
</Hr>
```

What do you do then?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I can learn a lot from your answer. Firstly however, I am having this error:
Can't locate XML/Twig.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/li
b .) at copy.plx line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at copy.plx line 6.

It is coming from this line:

use XML::Twig;

Is this something to do with the version of Perl I am using?

Comment: You need to install `XML::Twig`. If you are using ActivePerl, use `ppm install XML::Twig`.